# General Solution of $y'' -2y' +y = e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am searching for the general Solution of $$y'' -2y' +y = e^x$$
I know that $y = y_{part} + y_{hom}$ and the characteristic polynomial $p(T) = T^2 -2T +1 \stackrel{p(T) =0}\implies a =1  $ is the the only
root and $y_{hom} = C_1\exp(x)+ C_2x\exp(x)$ with $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbb{C}$. But I don't know how to find $y_{part}$.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**

Life could be easier starting with $y=z\, e^x$ which makes the equation to be
$$z''=1$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Congratulations, sir!

Comment: @Rohan. Thank you ! But this is a very trivial trick.

Comment: Sir, congrats for crossing a reputation mark!

Comment: @Rohan. Thanks ! You are the first doing that. Be sure I appreciate it (as well as I appreciate your answers on this splendid site. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you! But i don't understand it. So with $y = ze^x$ we get $(ze^x)''-2(ze^x)' + ze^x = e^x$ and $(ze^x)'' = ze^x = (ze^x)'$ so we have $0=e^x$

Comment: @AnnaSaabel. $y'(x)=e^x z'(x)+e^x z(x)$ and $y''=e^x z''(x)+2 e^x z'(x)+e^x z(x)$. Replace and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $y_p=Ax^2e^x$ and substitute in your equation to find $A$.

Answer (score 1):

When the function on the RHS is of the form $f(x) =e^{ax}$, we can find the particular integral by using the formula: $$y_p (x) = \frac{1}{F(a)} e^{ax}$$ Here, $F(D) = D^2-2D+1$ and the $a = 1$, so we have $F(a)= F(1)=0$.

In this case, what we do is: as $(D-1)$ is a factor of $F(D)$ with multiplicity $2$, we get, $$y_p (x) = x^2 \frac{1}{F’’(a)} e^{ax}$$

This gives us: $$y_p(x) = \frac{x^2e^x}{2}$$

Comment: In your first equation you probably wish to write $1/F(D)$ instead of $1/F(a)$. Also it is not clear how you get from that to the final $x^{2}/F''(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

One must get the idea and proof of the standard technique. We can write the given equation as $$y''-y' - (y'-y) =e^{x} $$ and then put $z=y'-y$ to get $$z'-z=e^{x} $$ Multiplication by $e^{-x} $ gives us $$(e^{-x} z) '=1$$ On integrating we get $$ze^{-x} =x+c$$ so that $$y' - y=z=xe^x+ce^x$$ Again multiplication by $e^{-x} $ gives us $$(ye^{-x}) '=x+c$$ Integrating this we get $$ye^{-x} =\frac{x^2}{2}+cx+d$$ and thus the general solution is $$y=e^x\left(d+cx+\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

---

This is how one solves a general differential equation with constant coefficients. You should also observe that there is no concept of general solution based on characteristic equation and particular integral. Most textbooks offer a completely mechanical procedure to obtain general solution based on nature of roots of characteristic equation and certain forms of particular integral for well known functions appearing on right side of the given differential equation. Frankly speaking I never liked that kind of spoon feeding without any proof.

Comment: I enjoy the last sentence !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: but your trick makes the problem trivial (+1 for your solution which I saw just now). And congrats for the 100k reputation. I have a long way to go before I reach there someday.

Comment: Thanks for your congratulations ! Looking at your work on this site and at your blog, I am sure that you will have a fast increasing reputation. Seriously speaking, you are the kind of people I enjoy(ed) to work with. Cheers.